# Selecting Inner nested text only

Tags: regex, regular-language

I'm using REGEX to select custom tags, however some of these tags have inner tags of the same name. I want to only select the inner tags, so i can process them first.

My REGEX is getting mixed up. I think this might require a recursive select, but I'm not sure how.

```
\[STORE.*?\]((.*?|\n)*)\[\/STORE\]
```

Text:

> ```
>  [STORE SMC, DODO]blah blah blah blah blah
>
>    [STORE SMC]blah[/STORE]
>
>    [STORE DODO]Blah[/STORE].
>
>  [/STORE]
>
>  Some text here I do not want selected.
>
>  [STORE SMC]blah[/STORE]
> ```

Select the tags in another run or the same run?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ls6Eygt.png

Comment: Ha, ok fair enough. I'm using APEX (salesforce) which is derived from Java. We have pattern and matcher classes.I believe javascript will work.

Comment: What are your expected matches?

Comment: @c14kaa that's the primary information I needed to know. Forget about recursion, your flavor doesn't support it, you'll haveto figure out some other way, perhaps by matching your regex multiple times on its results (doing the recursion yourself).

Comment: @anubhava Either : Only nested tags OR i can also work with Nested + stand alone tag at the end of my example.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Yes Lucas, I have been playing with doing it by self referencing using \1 \2 \3 But I'm a little lost as to where to place this.

Comment: Use a greedy match `.*` instead of `.*?` in the body part of the pattern, maybe you could use `(?s:.*)` with your flavor instead of `(.*|\n)*` altogether. Then do it again recursively on the matched substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex that uses a negative lookaahead to assert that we don't get another `[STORE ...]` in-between before the ending `[/STORE]`:

```
\[STORE [^\]]*\](?:(?!\[STORE [^\]]*\])[\s\S])*?\[\/STORE\]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DXv0ep/4)

This will match the inner most `STORE` tags or parent level independent `STORE` tags.

I've provided you a Javascript syntax. If you're using Java (Salesforce apax) then you can use:

```
String = regex = "\\[STORE [^]]*\\](?:(?!\\[STORE [^]]*\\]).)*?\\[/STORE\\]";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: Many thanks for getting this! I have been scratching y head all day figuring it out. Much appreciated.